# HTML Button is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

This button is not working in Firefox. Can someone help about his.

```
<li>
    <button name="button" onclick="javascript:redirectTo();">Submit</button> 
</li>
```

and JavaScript is:

```
function redirectTo()
{
    window.location.href = "myOtherPage.php" ;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: IIRC you don't need `javascript:` in the HTML.

Comment: Works fine for me in FF.

Comment: why the `return false;` ? it's not that the browser will do anything special on BUTTON click...

Comment: If my answer was useful, tap the checkmark below it, so as everybody will understand that your problem is solved

Answer (score 3):

Remove `javascript:` from `onClick`:

`<button name="button" onclick="redirectTo();">Submit</button>`

You need `javascript:` if using hyperlink, e.g:

```
<a href="javascript:redirectTo()">Hyperlink</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `<a href="...">` tag, is necessary add the javascript event in the href:
For example:

```
<button name="button" onclick="javascript:redirectTo();">Submit</button>
```

And without changes in your javascript

```
function redirectTo()
{
    window.location.href = "myOtherPage.php" ;
    return false;
}
```